# QR Code Detection with ZBar and ZXing failing for certain valid QR codes

Tags: imagemagick, qr-code, zxing, zbar

I am facing a really weird problem with QR code detection.

**TL;DR**

To put it really simply, both ZBar and ZXing fail to detect QR codes in many images.

[Example image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UTrVv5kHTcdgncfUQw9Xc295A21AXCj6/view?usp=sharing). ([Mirror](https://img42.com/PC7IS)).

On my mac, I have `zbar` installed through Brew. I have `zxing` setup using the JARs from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/). Both fail to detect the QR code in the example image. (Note: detection does work for many other images; I am not making any silly mistake in executing zbar or zxing.)

But if I open the "[Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en)" app on my phone and hold it up in front of my laptop screen showing the above QR code, the app detects it. Also, if I upload the above image on zxing.org, it detects the QR code there as well.

What could be wrong?

**Long version**

I have many physical sheets of paper with valid QR codes printed on them (similar to the example image above). The QR codes are detected perfectly, directly off the paper using any mobile app camera barcode scanner.

Next, I scan these sheets of paper using 2 scanners, at 300 DPI:

1. Fujitsu ScanSnap S1300i
2. Brother ADS-1500W

The output format is JPG (no other option in the scanner software of both scanners).

When I run zbar on any image produced by the Fujitsu scanner (scanning using their ScanSnap software), the QR code is ALWAYS detected.

When I run zbar (or zxing) on the images produced by the Brother scanner, the QR code detection is very much hit and miss.

**Actual case**: I scanned 31 sheets on the Brother scanner. The images are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oe8Aw7bQ0M6W6nJDM8IfmKjtL_3KrluQ?usp=sharing) (non G-Drive [mirror](http://www.mediafire.com/file/be4571c3435730e/Brother-20180517T125418Z-001.zip) with untouched images). Then I wrote a script to run through each image and find the QR code in it. Script [here](https://github.com/t-anjan/barcode-checker).

The full output of the script is produced on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/1ZvSbB9Q).

Summary of the Brother scanner images:

```
Total number of images scanned: 31

Num images with ZBAR QR detected: 17 
Num images ZBAR FAILED: 14

Num images with ZXING QR detected: 15 
Num images ZXING FAILED: 16
```

You can see that the QR code is not detected for many images by both software. And for some images, only one of the 2 software succeeds. For many other images, both succeed.

`05161801.JPG` is one image from the above set, which was not detected by both software. But the same image uploaded to zxing.org works. The barcode scanner app on my phone also detects the QR code off my laptop screen for this image.

**Hints**

The fact that QR detection works for the same sheets of paper when they are scanned with the Fujitsu scanner tells me that the Brother scanner is applying some post processing which is causing the QR detection to become iffy (this still does not explain how zxing.org works for these images, though). I am wondering if imagemagick can be used to somehow make the image work with ZBar. I tried to do some "enhancing" with [Fred's `textcleaner`](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/) script. I haven't been able to crack it yet.

I have spent a LOT of time trying to figure this out. I would appreciate any inputs, suggestions or solutions. Thanks!

**UPDATE: Adding the images of the SAME sheets of paper scanned using the Fujitsu scanner**

You can download the *untouched* images from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8d3s1mlbsa20cwc/Fuj31-SO.zip).

I ran the `barcode_checker.py` script (same as above) on these Fujitsu images. As mentioned earlier, the QR code is detected in EVERY SINGLE IMAGE! (ZXING does fail for a few, but ZBAR is 100% successful)

The full output of the script is produced on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/XcGSRuuX).

Summary of the Brother scanner images:

```
Total number of images scanned: 31

Num images with ZBAR QR detected: 31
Num images ZBAR FAILED: 0

Num images with ZXING QR detected: 26
Num images ZXING FAILED: 5
```

Comment: I can't actually download any of your images - too many redirects...

Comment: @MarkSetchell - The images are hosted on Google Drive. They open just fine for me, even in an incognito window. Anyway, I have added mirrors to the files now. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample from the Fujitsu scanner too please? Can you provide original samples of both that have not been uploaded to a website that has stripped all the meta-data out of them please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I wanted to scan the same 31 sheets on the Fujitsu scanner and run a comparison. But unfortunately, I will not get the scanner back in my hands till 22 May. Meanwhile, I have a couple of older untouched images produced by the Fujitsu scanner. I have zipped them and uploaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/89ke6853aj5i75f/Original%20Fujitsu%20Scans.zip). And the "[mirror](http://www.mediafire.com/file/be4571c3435730e/Brother-20180517T125418Z-001.zip)" link in the original post is also a ZIP file of untouched images produced by the Brother scanner.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - as requested by you, I have scanned the exact sheets using the Fujitsu scanner too. I have updated the post with those files. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and you don't appear to be applying any image processing or clean-up to the images? Could you clarify exactly what you have tried please?

---

Just a partial answer, but no-one said answers must be complete. Maybe I know 35% of the story and some clever soul knows the other 65% - are you reading Fred (@fmw42)?

Ok, I chose the (hopefully matching) pair of images:

- 05161825.JPG (Brother) - shown on left in diagram below
- 2018_05_25_10_19_46.JPG (Fujitsu) - shown on right

and analysed them with **ImageMagick**'s `identify -verbose IMAGE.JPG` tool and ran a difference on the outputs.

They correlate extremely closely, except where marked in red. I see the entropy is consistently lower in the Brother scan, the JPEG quality is unspecified (?) and the file size is around 35% less.

[image]

Maybe Fred, or Eric or some other kind folk have some insights. I will continue to look for further ideas and update my post as and when anything new occurs to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Mark. The pair of images you picked are indeed a matching pair. But you may want to pick a different pair, because the QR code in the Brother image you picked is actually detected by zbar. Maybe you can try the following pair: `05161832.JPG (Brother` and `2018_05_25_10_21_35.jpg (Fujitsu).

Comment: Regarding the image processing I tried: I just played around with `textcleaner` like: `textcleaner -e stretch -o 10 -f 40 -t 40 -T -u -g 05161832.JPG result1.jpg`. Tried various parameter values. I also cropped just the QR from the Brother image, loaded it in GIMP and  applied various filters, and tried the QR detection after each filter.